# How can i order the eager loaded model in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-plugins

I shot a find query to include certain models in rails but i want to order the included  models by my custom  criterion. I  have shot the  query like the following to fetch the qualifications  associated with the user ordering the qualifications by the start_date:

```
@user = User.find @current_user.id, :include => [:profile, {:qualifications=>{:order=>'start_date DESC'}}]
```

But when  i run this in rails, it says that it can't find association named order. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it in your model

```
has_many :qualifications, :order => "start_date DESC"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to order individually per find, do it this way:

`@user = User.find @current_user.id, :include => [:profile, :qualifications], :order=>'qualifications.start_date DESC'`

That means, move the table name into the order option.